# Convert JSON nested data into PHP array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm receiving in real time a json array from a server. 
This is the structure:

```
{
"success":true,
"message":"",
"result":
    [{  "MarketName":"BTC-1ST",
        "High":0.00003944,
        "Low":0.00003350,
        "Volume":1844905.50329604,
        "Last":0.00003655,
        "BaseVolume":67.77017463,
        "TimeStamp":"2017-12-01T15:49:50.037",
        "Bid":0.00003655,
        "Ask":0.00003662,
        "OpenBuyOrders":110,
        "OpenSellOrders":3412,
        "PrevDay":0.00003659,
        "Created":"2017-06-06T01:22:35.727"},

    {   "MarketName":"BTC-2GIVE",
        "High":0.00000071,
        "Low":0.00000064,
        "Volume":26833879.82630229,
        "Last":0.00000066,
        "BaseVolume":18.39542245,
        "TimeStamp":"2017-12-01T15:43:01.267",
        "Bid":0.00000065,
        "Ask":0.00000066,
        "OpenBuyOrders":136,
        "OpenSellOrders":1663,
        "PrevDay":0.00000063,
        "Created":"2016-05-16T06:44:15.287”}]
}
```

What I need to do is assigning some values from the json that I get in input to a php array of arrays that has to have the following matrix structure:

```
| Symbol_first_array_element Ask_Price_first_array_element Volumes_first_array_element |
| Symbol_second_array_element Ask_Price_second_array_element Volumes_second_array_element |
| Symbol_n_array_element Ask_Price_n_array_element Volumes_n_array_element |
```

For instance:

```
| 1ST 0.00003662 1844905.50329604 |
| 2GIVE 0.00000066 26833879.82630229 |
```

Also I want to populate this array of arrays only from elements that contain "BTC" in their MarketName. This means that I need to check in a loop that all the objects that I'm inserting in my array of arrays have a MarketName of "BTC-whatever else".

Could you kindly help me? I'm pretty new to php.

Comment: look up `json_decode()` in the PHP Manual

Comment: once you try, we will help you when it gets tough. 
1. json_decode the server result
2.loop over it

Comment: where is your code ? try something as @imox said

Comment: Ok, I'll do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. As someone said in the comments above I just had to play around a bit with the code. 
Anyway, here's my solution:

```
    $json_url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries';
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $obj = json_decode($jsondata, TRUE); 
    $coins = array();
    $i = 0;
    $n = max(array_map('count', $obj)); 
    /*
    * With the SLOC above I get from Bittrex all the JSON data required,
    * then I fetch it, I assign it to an object, I declare the $coins array
    * and finally I assign to the $n variable the number of occurences inside 
    * the array.
    */


        for($i; $i < $n+1; $i++){

            /* Inside this if selection I check that the i-th coin is traded
            *  against BTC (Bitcoin) 
            */
            if (strpos($obj['result'][$i]['MarketName'], 'BTC-') !== false) { 


                /* The next three SLOC are self-explaining, I suppose. 
                *  I just perform an assignment to variables from the i-th
                *  element inside the array
                */
                $symbol = $obj['result'][$i]['MarketName'];
                $ask_price = $obj['result'][$i]['Ask'];
                $volumes = $obj['result'][$i]['Volume'];

                $coins[$i] = array(
                    "symbol" => $symbol,
                    "ask_price" => $ask_price,
                    "volumes" => $volumes,
                    "%_var_price" => 0,
                    "%_var_volumes" => 0,
                ); 

            }           


        }
```